# How to feed a class a list of options through a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying out classes in javascript also using extend.js to create them. I am having some trouble with classes and am not really sure if I need them, but I think this one will be useful. It's a class to just get some database table data.

```
var TableData = Class.extend(function(){
   this.rowId;
   this.action;
   this.returnWhat;
   this.tableType;
   this.php;

   this.query = function(){ 
      if (this.returnWhat) this.action += '_' + this.returnWhat;
      var postData = { func : this.action };
      if (this.rowId) $.extend(postData, { rowId : this.rowId });
      $.post(this.php, postData, function(data){
        if(data){this.data = data;}
      });   
    return this.data;   
   };

});
```

I will have only tables that I know of, so I just store them as vars/options, but I don't  know how to set the class vars up properly. This for example does not work but maybe demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

```
var options = {
    rowId : '*',
    action : 'get',
    returnWhat : 'all'
}

var league = function (options){
    this.tableType    = 'league';
    this.rowId        = options.rowId;
    this.action       = options.action;
    this.returnWhat   = options.returnWhat;
    this.php          = 'php/' + options.tableType + '.php';
}

var tableData = new TableData(assoc_league);
```

Comment: mmm, that is a crazy way to achieve something simple. plus in var league, you would probably be better setting this.php to use this.tableType, otherwise in your example, it will be undefined

Comment: Yeah I thought so. What I don't know is if its because I'm using the idea of a Class wrong, or because I shouldn't be using a class.

Comment: also $.post is async so return this.data, will not return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like this idea

```
(function(my, $){
    var cfg = {
        rowId: null,
        action: null,
        returnWhat: null,
        tableType: null,
        url: null
    };

    my.init = function(options) {
        if (options != undefined) {
            for (var k in options) {
                if (!options.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
                cfg[k] = options[k];
            }
        }
        return this;
    };

    my.fetchData = function(data, callback) {
        $.post(cfg.url, data, function(resp) {
            callback(resp);
        });
    }
})(window.myapp, window.jQuery);

//---------------
myapp.init({
    url: '/blah/blah'
})
.fetchData({animal1: 'monkey', animal2: 'zebra'}, function(data){

});
```

Comment: im not sure whether its return this or return $... test and see :)

Comment: ive just realised a floor in my code.. will correct now. cant have jquery and myapp as $ :)

Comment: I don't remember why I chose this as the answer - I get my is undefined

Comment: Oh it is just the brackets should be  }(window.myapp, window.jQuery));

Comment: hi tester232323, what browser did you test it in?